# Choosing which columns to be exported from MySQL to Excel using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, excel, pandas

Using `mysql.connector`, I have made a MySQL query in python that is read by `pd.read_sql_query`, The code is as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
db_con= mysql.connector(user=..., pass=..., host:..., database='db')
query= ("""SELECT tagnumber,value,content,tagname 
            FROM db.table
            WHERE tagnumber>=%d AND tagname='XXX' AND content!="";""" % (2))

df=pd.read_sql_query(query,db_con,index_col=['value','content'])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

However, while it correctly indexes the 'value' and 'content' for me, when I export the query to excel file, it will also show 'tagnumber' and 'tagname' columns in my excel file which I don't need. I only want to print the columns I want to be shown in the excel sheet (which are 'value and 'content'). How can I select which column(s) to write to excel file using Pandas sql_read in this case?

Comment: Would it work if you use this - `SELECT value,content FROM db.table WHERE...` instead of what you are using now?

Comment: If you mean that I put all the sql query within a single line (instead of 3), I tried and I say No, it makes no difference

Comment: Fasa, I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an other correction if you don't want to change your query

```
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.filter(items=['value','content']).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index = False)
        writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the SQL Query like this:

```
query= ("""SELECT value,content
            FROM db.table
            WHERE tagnumber>=%d AND tagname='XXX' AND content!="";""" % (2))
```